# Same font-size everywhere

Tags: css, font-size

I would like to have a uniform font-size everywhere. This is not the case right now and I do not know where the bug is.

For example the font size here in [page 1](http://www.marmsoft.nl/It-diensten/) is different from that in [page 2](http://www.marmsoft.nl/website-bouwer/website-maken/). (I do not need to target IE8 and lower. My target audience is Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.)

By the way, what is `main copy`?

Comment: According to the website that company makes websites. And there's nobody who can help you there?

Comment: I'm not seeing the font size difference in FF or Chrome.  Can you point to some specific text that is a problem?

Comment: Maybe some clever disguise for Advertisement? Well, maybe not that clever...

Comment: @Nirazul clever? Not at all. That whole site must be a joke.

Comment: @DennisTraub: Why do you say that?  The OP seems to have a legitimate history.

Comment: Joke? Are you crazy? I have IT background and have knowledge of software development, design, UML, etc, but I do not know everything. I have no company , but I work for myself. Nobody knows everything.
In my country every software developer have  knowledge of UML, HTML, CSS, Java,. Net.

Comment: @cale_b,  the font size in page1 is larger than that in page2. See links above. 
If you do not see that, I have problem with my eyes.

Comment: @Nirazul, can jou create an advertisement for a website that is not ready  and full  with bugs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up `style.css` in any text editor.
2. Find all `font-size` rules.
3. Delete them all.
4. Create a new rule: `body { font-size: size; }` where `size` is the value you want.